# Is DriversHQ Software - 'Driver detective' malware?

Tags: malware

Is DriversHQ Driver detective a malware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [user reviews over on CNET](http://download.cnet.com/Driver-Detective/3000-18513_4-10175742.html), Driver Detective is probably "crapware", although not specifically malicious.

Like Diago mentions, there are plenty of sites distributing legit software with malware attached. Often best to run some anti-malware scans just in case.

Comment: +1 Just because the Geek referred to me in his answer :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.pcpitstop.com/libraries/process/i/DriversHQ.DriverDetective.Client.exe.html) the correct answer is no.

I am aware however of some sites distributing it without permission and it does contain malware, however this type of software you should only ever install from the original source.